# Redefining initial stack pointer value for stm32f3

Tags: c, linker, arm, stm32, ld

I have an stm32f303 discovery board, and I'm trying to understand the linking and relocating process more. I'm compiling and running this example here: https://github.com/mblythe86/stm32f3-discovery-basic-template

The reset stack pointer value is defined in the vector table in the setup script Device/startup_stm32f30x.s. The original value is 0x2000A000 (ie. initial SRAM address + 32K).
The only other things I can see that are allocated to the SRAM are the .data and .bss sections:

```
 2 .data         0000004c  20000000  08000e94  00020000  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  3 .bss          00000040  2000004c  08000ee0  0002004c  2**2
                  ALLOC
```

So (ignoring the stack) everything from address 0x2000008c - 0x40000000 should be free for me to use as far as SRAM is concerned?

I try decreasing the initial stack pointer value by 32 bytes (from 0x2000A000 to 0x20009FD0) in the startup script and we compile and run everything fine.

I try increasing the initial stack pointer value by 32 bytes (from 0x2000A000 to 0x2000A020) and things stop working.

Running GDB and breaking at the SystemInit function, the disassembly that is causing the problem looks like:

```
08000c18 <SystemInit>:
 8000c18:   b580        push    {r7, lr}
 8000c1a:   af00        add r7, sp, #0
 8000c1c:   4a1f        ldr r2, [pc, #124]  ; (8000c9c <SystemInit+0x84>)
 8000c1e:   4b1f        ldr r3, [pc, #124]  ; (8000c9c <SystemInit+0x84>)
 8000c20:   f8d3 3088   ldr.w   r3, [r3, #136]  ; 0x88
```

at which point we trigger an exception of some kind and jump to `WWDG_IRQHandler`. The value of r3 at the ldr.w instruction is 0xe000ed00, which appears to be something on the peripheral device bus?

The confusing part for me is that this section of code and all of the register and memory addresses are identical in the original version that works (except for the stack pointer value, of course), including the ldr.w memory access at 0xe000ed00 + 0x88. Any idea what is going on here? Is there something else managing the initial stack pointer besides the vector table?

Comment: STM32F303VCT6 microcontroller featuring 256‑Kbyte Flash memory and 48‑Kbyte RAM in an LQFP100 package

Comment: you most definitely cannot use 0x2000008c - 0x40000000

Comment: your sram is from 0x20000000 to 0x2000BFFF as documented by ST

Comment: 0xe000ed00 should be in the arm documentation.

Comment: yes, confirmed, it is in the arm documentation.

Comment: what did the github author say when asked about this problem with their code?

Comment: If interested in linking and relocating, first off you dont need to execute any code to learn/understand.  Second, use some simple code, not something so complicated.

Comment: The upper bound of 0x40000000 was my misinterpretation of the data sheet. 0x2000A020 is still well within 0x20000000 - 0x2000BFFF though

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the results you are seeing and poking around in the wrong place.  If your goal is to understand linking and relocating then there is no reason to execute anything examine the output of the tools.  But also own the code a few dozen lines of code is adequate to fulfill the goal.

Comment: please provide a complete example in the question of the problem, all source code and disassembly so we can see what you are running into.  (make it a minimal complete example that demonstrates the problem).

Comment: Looks like my board only has 40K of SRAM, and the existing comment on the linker script was wrong... A000 is 40K, not 32K. So trying to set the stack pointer to A020 put us over the edge of the RAM, probably caused some chaos when we tried to push things onto the stack at that point.

Comment: @old_timer I afraid you are 100% wrong. 48k SRAM is no congnous. It has 40k SRAM and 8k CCM RAM. SRAM is at  the address 0x20000000 and the CCM RAM is at the 0x10000000.

Comment: makes sense, still isnt relevant to the question, the OP is poking at stuff without reading nor understanding and chasing red herrings.  the easiest way to understand linking and relocation is to not run the code but simply look at the compiler output, more painful to use gdb as a disassembler when you have a disassembler handy.  but before you can do that you need to understand the code in general, the bootstrap, etc.  starting with something overcomplicated for the job is not helping.

Comment: Not sure why you are so worked up over this. I was changing the stack pointer entry in the vector table and examining the value of the stack pointer at runtime with GDB. Seems pretty simple to me. As can seen above, I worked out my problem anyway. Thanks for your opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advices.

1. Download a bit more user friendly IDE with decent debugger GUI. For example atollic studio.
2. Stop using found somewhere on the net "templates". This one uses prehistoric SPL library - not supported any more by STM. Use CubeMx to generate the project templates.
3. you have 48k of RAM but divided into two different memory areas. 40k SRAM(0x20000000 - 0x2000A000) and CCM RAM (0x10000000 - 0x10002000)
4. As per point 3. the last address of the SRAM is 0x2000A000 so when you place the stack at 0x2000A020 - you instantly end up in the HardHault handler. (It is not WDG as in your startup all HFs are handled by one function)
5. You can also place the stack in the CCM RAM.
6. This is the simplest configuration - ARM cores have 2 stacks used by the user and the privileged code.
7. Stack does not have to be at the end of the memory area. I often prevere to place it at the beginning. When the stack overflows it invokes the HF giving me the chance to take action. If stack is at the end of the RAM it may silently overflow overwriting the data stored in RAM
8. **Always read** the full documentation. Datasheet, Reference manual & programming manual

Comment: Interesting DV - any reason? Bad mood or revenge

Comment: I don't think the point about IDE use is relevant to the question (I didn't mention which IDE I use...) and I have yet to find a gui that is any more useful than the GDB TUI that is also applicable to desktop linux dev. But you did address my question and explained why it was leading to the exception I was seeing, so I will take this as the accepted answer. I guess the exception handler is triggered by the initial stack push at instruction address 8000c18? Do you know why the PC does not jump to the handler until 4 instructions later?

Comment: Ah, probably because the CPU is pipelined and takes a few cycles to execute the original push?

Comment: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0439b/CHDDIGAC.html would indicate 3 cycles to execute the push here, so that plus 2 cycles for the fetch and decode would seem to coincide correctly with the fault handling.

Comment: @MatthewHampsey pipelining  matters here. It just makes HF imprecise. Pipeline is being flushed when exception arrives. For uC develoment good IDE matters as well. Atollic has many very handy debug plugins like HF analysers (it ssaves sa looooots of time), RTOS aware debugging etc etc.